# QGIS Draw Polygon Exact Dimension

Tags: qgis, polygon

I am wondering if there is a way to show an area of a polygon as you draw it. I trying to create a perfect 1 acre polygon, but the polygon could have 1-20 sides. I don't really want to have to do $area in the attribute table every time to find my area.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This could be of some relevance to you. It explains how to make a field update its value when editing the features of a layer. Just open your attribute table and see the fields update as you move your points around. [spatialthoughts.com](https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/04/12/summary-aggregation-qgis/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can label your features with the area of each polygon after you have saved the edit to the shapefile/database.

In the label value, use something like this:

```
round(AREA(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:2877'))*'0.00002295682', 2) || ' ac'
```

What this is doing is:

- transforming the geometry from WGS84 (4326) to a localized projected coordinate system (State Plane CO Central is 2877)
- calculating the AREA of the transformed geometry - in square feet
- multiplying it by the conversion factor from sq feet to acres
- rounding to 2 decimal places
- appending the 'ac' abbreviation at the end

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use OpenJUMP for digitizing. It shows runtime info about the the new feature and the last segment. However, it does not show that info when an existing feature is edited.

[image: OpenJUMP info about a new feature while it is digitized]

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would like to do, but for QGIS since that's where all my files are.